# tokenInput : how to pass additional parameter with queryParam

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

I am using Jquery Token Input. I need to know, how to pass additional parameter with queryParam.

**Script :**

```
$("#demo-input").tokenInput("/MaterialService/GetMaterials",
{
    queryParam: 'q',
    tokenLimit: 1,
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Property> GetMaterials(string q, String type)
{
    //Code for the function
}
```

I need to access the function 'GetMaterials' in Service Controller.
Where In my script, I have have queryParam (i.e. 'q') and another parameter 'type'

while calling the service controller, how i need to pass the 'type' parameter along with the queryParam

Can anyone help?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this and feedback results:

```
$("#demo-input").tokenInput("/MaterialService/GetMaterials?queryParam=q" + "&type=qq",
                { tokenLimit: 1, });
```

Comment: This works but i noticed that the results are cached. if the parameter changes then it is not reflecting